# Show that in the ring of quaternions every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse

Tags: ring-theory

I've got this math question for my training to my algebra exam.

"Show that in the ring of quaternions every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse"

The worst case is that my text book only contain a problem with quaternions but no theorems etc. How can I attach this problem and show it?

Yours,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Any quaternion can be written $a+bi+cj+dk$, where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now try to compute $$(a+bi+cj+dk)(a-bi-cj-dk)$$

And look for something to multiply with $a+bi+cj+dk$ to get $1$.

Comment: I'm new to this - if I compute the expression you have, where a,b,c and d are reals, then I get a hell long expession. I can eliminate i^2, j^2 and k^2 but I still have a long expression. I hope you can see what I mean

Comment: It will simplify to something really nice, trust me! And you're right about $i^2$, and so on being eliminated since $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$. But you get the main idea, right? If you find something to multiply $a+bi+cj+dk$ with to get $1$, then you have shown that $a+bi+cj+dk$ has an inverse.

Comment: I am trying, and I'm looking at this table: https://puu.sh/z7fOa/c3c2403265.png but It seems not clear for me. I can not get it to something nice as you state

Comment: Write what you've got, and I'll help you. Just remember that $i\cdot j=k$ and that $j\cdot i=-k$, in other words the order when multiplying matters!

Comment: Okay, here:
$a^2-a\cdot ib-a\cdot cj-a\cdot dk+ib\cdot a+b^2-ib\cdot cj-ib\cdot dk+cj\cdot a-cj\cdot ib+c^2-cj\cdot dk+dk\cdot a-dk\cdot ib-dk\cdot cj+d^2$

Am I right? Btw I will look at your newest comment

Comment: If I factor I get: 
$a^2+b^2-2ibcj-2ibdk+c^2-2jdk+d^2$
=$a^2+b^2-2bck-2ibdk+c^2-2cjdk+d^2$

Comment: Now collect the real parts, the $i$ part, the $j$ part and the $k$ part.  Now is there a number that you can multiply by the result that will give you the identity.

Comment: $ik = k, ji = -k,$ etc.

Comment: I can see my expression becomes smaller and smaller. I get
$2bdj-2bck-2icd+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$

Comment: You have transposed something in your multiplication.... you should get $(a+bi+cj+dk)(a-bi-cj-dk) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 -abi + abi -cdjk - cdkj + acj-acj -bdik - bdki \cdots $ and the $ij$ terms and the $ji$ terms cancel.

Comment: @KasperMedK Everything that you wrote in your third comment was correct. The hard part is to simplify. You got (and I'm writing it slightly different):

$a^2-(ab)\cdot i-(ac)\cdot j-(ad)\cdot k+(ab)\cdot i+b^2-(bc)(i\cdot j)-(bd)(i\cdot k)+(ac)\cdot j-(bc)(j\cdot i)+c^2-(cd)(j\cdot k)+(ad)\cdot k-(bd)(k\cdot i)-(cd)(k\cdot j)+d^2$.

Now use that $i\cdot j=k$ and $j\cdot i=-k$, together with $j\cdot k=i$, $k\cdot j=-i$, $k\cdot i=j$, and $i\cdot k=-j$.

Comment: Yes I know I did a mistake somewhere. 
I checked and now I get this: 

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-2(bc)(ij)-2(bd)(ik)-2(cd)(jk)$


=$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-2bc(ij)-2bd(ik)-2cd(jk)$


=$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-2bc(k)-2bd(-j)-2cd(i)$


=$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-2bc(k)+2bd(j)-2cd(i)$

Comment: Ohh sorry! I see I just multiply everything. Am I right if I say this is wrong (just an example): $i\cdot j \neq j\cdot i$ ? I will do my calculations again!

Comment: @KasperMedK Yes! :D Let's start from this:

$a^2-(ab)\cdot i-(ac)\cdot j-(ad)\cdot k+(ab)\cdot i+b^2-(bc)(i\cdot j)-(bd)(i\cdot k)+(ac)\cdot j-(bc)(j\cdot i)+c^2-(cd)(j\cdot k)+(ad)\cdot k-(bd)(k\cdot i)-(cd)(k\cdot j)+d^2$. And let us make life a little bit easier by collecting the terms with the same coefficient:

$a^2+(ab)(-i+i)+(ac)(-j+j)+(ad)(-k+k)+b^2+(bc)(-i\cdot j-j\cdot i)+(bd)(-i\cdot k-k\cdot i)+c^2+(cd)(-j\cdot k-k\cdot j)+d^2$. And you're right that $i\cdot j\neq j\cdot i$, so what is $i\cdot j$, and what is $j\cdot i$?

Comment: Thanks! I recalculate everything and ends with $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ :D but now what should I do? I got so far but I think it's not the answer for the question?

Comment: NP! :) Now, you have to find something to multiply with $a+bi+cj+dk$ to get $1$. What you've found out is that $(a+bi+cj+dk)(a-bi-cj-dk)=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ (the right-hand side is a number). Can you rearrange this equation to get $(a+bi+cj+dk)(\operatorname{something})=1$? (And that "something" has to be a quaternion)

Comment: I can multiply with $1/(a+bi+cj+dk)$ such that $(a+bi+cj+dk)$ would disappere? :)

Comment: Well, $1/(a+bi+cj+dk)$ is by definition the inverse, but you don't know that $1/(a+bi+cj+dk)=a'+b'i+c'j+d'k$. But what you can do is divide both sides by $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ (which is only a number). Then you get that $(a+bi+cj+dk)\frac{a-bi-cj-dk}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}=1$. 

So the inverse is $\frac{a}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}i-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}j-\frac{c}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}j-\frac{d}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}k$ and this holds only if $a\neq b\neq c\neq d\neq 0$, which means that the quaternion is non-zero!

Comment: Just a question you write in your calculations $c^2d^2$ above. Is that true? I mean, you did $c^2+d^2$ before? :) I will try to understand your calculations

Comment: @KasperMedK yes, my mistake! I meant $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ :) (I have edited the comment)

Comment: Great, I understand your calculations, thank you very much for your time!